# Rewriting the two dimensional heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

Consider the heat equation 
$$k\nabla^2u=k\left ( \frac{\partial^2u }{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2u }{\partial y^2} \right )=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$
in two dimensions, where $k$ is a constant.  By making the substitution $s=kt$, I want to show that this equation can be written as 
$$\frac{\partial^2u }{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2u }{\partial y^2} =\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}.$$
My initial thought was to just substitute directly using the fact that 
$$k=\frac{s}{t}.$$
However, this did not get me far.  I know I have to use the chain rule somehow, but right now I am not really seeing it.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial s}$$
Here,
$\frac{\partial t}{\partial s}=1/k$,
so
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} = \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$
Substitute for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, and the answer follows.

Comment: Short and simple.  Thanks!